# "How does the 'context' value in a Docker Compose file affect the meaning of '.' in a Dockerfile's 'COPY' instruction

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is a part of my `./docker/development/Dokcerfile`:

```
# ...
# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . ${APP_HOME}
# ...
```

and here my `./compose.yml`:

```yaml
# ...
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/local/django/Dockerfile
# ...
```

Now, I would like to know if the value of the context affects the meaning of "." in a `Dockerfile` or not?

Comment: It definitionally is the root of the _left-hand_ side of `COPY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the context path (the last parameter passed to `docker-compose up` or `docker build` commands) affects only the copy/add/workdir/etc commands.

The docker file can be in any folder you want, like for the `-f` parameter you should optionally use to tell the `docker` client about the `Dockerfile` location.

Comment: So, in order to copy the contents of the project root into the container, do I need to specify the root project path in a relative manner in the Dockerfile?

Comment: No, to the COPY command you must pass a path relative to the context path.

Comment: Please upvote too if solved.

Comment: I believe something is not right. I am watching a course in which the instructor set the `context` to `.` in the `compose.yml` file. Then in the `Dockerfile` located in `./docker/django/development`, the instructor wrote `COPY ./docker/django/development/start`. How can this be correct?